# Unable to insert COPY_SEND

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I try recover a document in a transaction. If the document doesn’t exist, I get the following error -> [Common] _BSMachError: port 29b33; (os/kern) invalid capability (0x14) "Unable to insert COPY_SEND” but I’m waiting a empty doc., a nil or anything different to a error

```
   database.runTransaction({ (transaction, errorPointer) -> Any? in

        var snapshot: DocumentSnapshot?
        do {
            try snapshot = transaction.getDocument(documentReference)
        } catch let fetchError as NSError {
            errorPointer?.pointee = fetchError
            return nil
        }

        if let document = snapshot, document.exists {
            errorPointer?.pointee = NSError(domain:
```

Thanks in advance for your responses.